# How to create a dynamically resizing table element in html and css

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I am creating a crossword generator and aim to use HTML and CSS, along with Jinja2 templates to represent the crossword.

I have chosen to use the `table` element to represent the crossword (the crossword is always square):

```
<table class="table">
    {% for row in range(dimensions) %}
        <tr>
            {% for column in range(dimensions) %}
                <td>{{ . }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I have had trouble making this table fill the screen appropriately; I am trying to make it expand outwards equally until it cannot expand any further, with a little bit of padding on either sides.

Could anyone help me write some CSS to ensure the table expands outwards dynamically, retaining a square shape, keeping a bit of padding on both sides and keeping all `<td>` elements an equal size?

Comment: Please start by showing the CSS you already tried (as runnable snippet), because you know how many letters you have, so you should know how to size `td` in percentages, with the table itself set to a 100% width.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have no CSS, also the amount of letters I have is not constant, the crossword is always going to be variable in its dimensions and word count.

Comment: Of course it is, but _you know the number of rows and columns_ because you're writing the software here. You know the size of your own crossword when you generate it, which means you know what the percentages are. If there are R rows and C columns, each cell is 100%/C wide and 100%/R tall, at most.

Comment: Do you know the words to be shown in advance?

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes. Although now, all I am trying to accomplish is to make the table always contain a variable amount of cells and be perfectly square.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes of course, but how do I use the dimensions variable inside of the CSS to specify this?

Comment: _Literally_ by doing that very thing. You set a CSS variable as part of your Jinja template, where you just template in `style="--rows: {{ rowCount }}; --columns: {{ colCount}}"` and then you write your CSS with `calc()` and `var()`. Lots of great pages on the web that teach you how to use CSS variables in combination with calc.

Comment: Ok this is very embarrasing but Jinja2 variables do work in the CSS. Pretty sure it has to be in the index.html though. I swear this didn't work before...

Comment: Jinja just replaces text with text, it has no concept of what a CSS variable is. This always worked =)

Comment: Thanks for the help Mike. Do I write `style="--rows: {{ rowCount }}; --columns: {{ colCount}}"` as inline CSS? And what does calc() and var() do? Sorry I don't know much I have only been using it for a few days.

Comment: Time to learn how far CSS has come: do some web searching on CSS variables and using `calc()` in CSS, because it lets you do a _ton_ of work in CSS that you'd otherwise be tempted to do in JS, when you _really_ don't need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that ?

```css
html {
  font-family     : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size       : 16px;
  color           : black;
  }
table {
  margin           : 2em;
  --td-siz         : 2em;
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 1px;       /* for cells borders */
  background-color : #252627;
  }
table td:not(:empty) {
  background : whitesmoke;
  width      : var(--td-siz);
  height     : var(--td-siz);
  text-align : center;
  text-transform : uppercase;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr> <td> W </td> <td> A </td> <td> L </td> <td> L </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td> I </td> <td> R </td> <td> O </td> <td> N </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td> N </td>   <td></td>  <td> c </td>   <td></td>  </tr>
  <tr> <td> G </td> <td> R </td> <td> I </td> <td> L </td> </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

/* .ruller and its styles are for demonstration purposes only */
.ruller {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
  text-align: right;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;

}
```

```html
<div class="ruller">
  <table>
    <tr><td>W<td>A<td>L<td>L
    <tr><td>I<td>R<td>O<td>N
    <tr><td>N<td><td><td>
    <tr><td>G<td>R<td>I<td>L
  </table>
  resize container here ↘
</div>
```

I hope I understood you correctly and you need the aspect-ratio property along with table-layout: fixed;

Answer (score -2):

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: auto;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {

  th,
  td {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 2</th>
            <th>Head 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>info 1</td>
            <td>Info 2</td>
            <td>Info 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).